# Верна ли здесь пунктуация?

Tags: пунктуация

Свое первое сочинение я помню довольно хорошо. Это именно тот случай, когда от счастья и нетерпения момент откладывается в памяти. На самом деле, не знаю, что такого особенного я вывела из этого , но для каждого первоклассника этот момент запоминается.
  Сидишь в предвкушении и ждешь, пока объявят твою оценку.
  Как-то я далеко зашла. Отмотаем назад.
  Точно помню, что в тот момент передо мной лежал красный учебник. Елена Викторовна, учительница младших классов, сказала:
  - Ребята, откройте *** страницу.
  Я открыла данную мне страницу, и она меня ничем не заинтересовала. Я начала листать дальше. Дальше и дальше. Быстрее и быстрее. Я пыталась прочесть хоть что-то. Вдруг на мой слух упада фраза:
  - А сейчас сочинение!
  Я естественно запаниковала:
  - Что это? Как это писать?
  К моему удивлению ни один одноклассник не волновался.
  Кто-то ждал пока раздадут тетради, кто-то исследовал голую стену, кто-то добывал полезные ископаемые в носу.
  Я совсем сошла с ума. То есть, я и так сидела с комом в горле, но еще и солнце вышло из-за облаков. Проглядывало через сосульки и било мне в глаз. От нахлынувших на меня эмоций у меня пошла кровь. Что естественно, то не безобразно.
  Так я и запомнила свое первое сочинение: головной болью, красным носом и кровавой страницей в учебнике.

Comment: ИЗ-ЗА не надо делить.

Comment: @shampar В каком смысле делить?

Comment: Это не к Вам,  М_Г, и не Тане, а к текстовому редактору, как оказалось: он разделил ИЗ-ЗА, приняв за перенос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прежде всего, замечание: для того чтобы сделать переход на другую строку видимым читателю этого сайта, нужно добавлять два пробела в конце строки, что я и сделал, отредактировав Ваш текст.

Далее.

- В тексте много стилистических ошибок, но это отдельный вопрос.
- Описка: "упада фраза".
- Лишний пробел перед запятой: "вывела из этого , но"

Если говорить и пунктуации, то я заметил следующие ошибки.

> На самом деле, не знаю, что такого особенного я вывела из этого , но для каждого первоклассника этот момент запоминается.

Вопрос о выделении слов "на самом деле" решается в зависимости от смысла фразы. Я понимаю, что слова "на самом деле" относятся к "не знаю" (я на самом деле не знаю). В таком случае запятая не ставится.

> Я естественно запаниковала

Здесь *естественно* — вводное слово, оно должно выделаться запятыми.

> Кто-то ждал пока раздадут тетради

Здесь не хватает запятой перед *пока*. (Запятая в СПП.)

> То есть, я и так сидела с комом в горле

*То есть* не является вводным, и после него не ставится запятая.